# Spring Web: replace org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I would like to replace `org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor` by a custom implementation. How can this be achieved? I couldn't find a hint in the application context or config?

Comment: Why would you want to replace this? What are you trying to achieve...

Comment: I would like to cache supportsReturnType().

Comment: Why? There is already a lot of caching going on in the methods being called (or actually the utility methods being called). Replacing it would require a `BeanPostProcessor` and hack around in the internals of the `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`.

Comment: For one page request I get 130 `NoSuchMethodException`s with stacktrace while searching for annotations `ModelAttribute`/`ResponseBody` walking up the hierarchy of my `AbstractCMSComponentController.handleGet()` of my CMS components looking for the non-existing method `AbstractController.handleGet()`. It's always the same non-existing method, but a different `MethodParameter` in `supportsReturnType()`.

Comment: @M.Deinum Actually I might even want to cache the calls of `org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils`

Comment: Isn't the main issue that you want to suppress to stack traces? Are those logged at a certain level?

Comment: AnnotatedElementUtils is scanning "aggressively" for annotation to find inherited annotations etc. To do so, it is also looking for method that don't exists (repeatingly). The NoSuchMethodException is thrown and catch right afterwards without logging. I'm concerned about the amount of useless generated stacktraces. This is especially annoying as my annotation are not changing at runtime.